# Master Detail view with yii framework

Tags: yii

I have been looking all over for an example of creating a master-detail view using yii - possibly using a dropdown list and a gridview.

I have two tables Objectives and Outputs where a given Objective can have one or more Outputs. I would like to populate the dropdown with the Objectives and display details of the Outputs (of selected Objective) in the gridview. Will be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a recent wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/323/dynamic-parent-and-child-cgridciew-on-single-view-using-ajax-to-update-child-gridview-via-controller-with-many_many-relation-after-row-in-parent-gridview-was-clicked/) that gives a solution using CGridViews for two tables having a MANY-MANY relationship with a third junction table specifying the relations. I think it could be adapted easily to your situation.